# Help with Process Builder and Visual Flows

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

Okay, so I have two Custom Objects, `Buyer's Order` and `Cap Cost`. `Cap Cost` has a Master-Detail to `Buyers Order`. I have a visual flow that when a `Buyers Order` meets certain criteria it will update all of the associated `Cap Cost` records by checking a box. I then would like to have a Process Builder get kicked off when that checkbox gets checked.

I tested this process with one `Cap Cost` on the `Buyers Order` and it worked. When I added a second `Cap Cost` to the `Buyers Order` it would only work for the first one and not the newly added one. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What object is a master?

Comment: Buyers Order is the Master of Cap Cost

Comment: It seems like you need also a Workflow Rule for new `Cap Cost` records to validate `Buyers Order` criteria and set a flag when needed

Comment: when adding a child object, the workflow/process builder on the parent won't execute unless something changes on the parent. This can include RSF fields